# mysql searching in various fields with OR performing full table scan

Tags: mysql, full-table-scan

I have 3 tables (not writing all and actual field names)

- Contract (~30 000 rows)

  |id|client_id|contract_nr|....
- Container (~30 000 rows

  |id|contract_nr|phone_1(varchar)|....
- Client (~35 000 rows)

  |id|phone_2(varchar)|phone_3(varchar)|phone_4(varchar)|....

I need to search for phone numbers so i try this - if i serch for one phone number for example in container.phone_1

```
SELECT *
FROM contract JOIN client
     ON contract.client_id = client.id
     JOIN container
     ON contract.contract_nr = container.contract_nr
WHERE container.phone_1 LIKE '264%' 

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE  container   range   contract_nr,phone_1 phone_1 63  NULL    912 100.00  Using where
1   SIMPLE  contract    ref contract_nr,client_id   contract_nr 26  container.contract_nr   1   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  client  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 3   contract.client_id  1   100.00
```

but when i start to add phone numbers from client using OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM contract JOIN client 
    ON contract.client_id = client.id 
    JOIN container ON contract.contract_nr = container.contract_nr 
WHERE (
    container.phone_1 LIKE '264%' OR 
    client.phone_2 LIKE '264%' OR 
    client_phone_3 LIKE '264%'
)
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows     filtered   Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE  container   ALL k_ligums,k_telef    NULL    NULL    NULL    32113   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  contract    ref contract_nr,client_id   contract_nr 26  za.zaao_konteineri.k_ligums 1   100.00  
1   SIMPLE  client  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id  PRIMARY 3   contract.client_id  1   100.00  Using where
```

I have indexed all the fields that are used to join tables and that are used to search for.
I also tried to create multiple-column index for client and container tables having all the search rows included - no difference.

How can i avoid scanning of 32113 rows for container table?

Comment: joins will kill query performance in a large dataset. consider avoiding them if possible or restructuring your data if you need to work with data at scale

Comment: The problem starts when I add "OR" in query - no problem with joins till that! Replaced joins with table1.field = table2.field - no difference - still fullscan performed!

Comment: The dataset size is not significant IMHO. If you do an `EXPLAIN SELECT * ...` you will get an execution plan. Please post up the results, as that helps tremendously with query performance issues.

Comment: "Explain extended" alerady is in my post!

Comment: Sorry mate - right you are - it seems mixing `like` conditions from 2 tables together is preventing the use of the index on container.phone_1. A real shot in the dark - have you tried changing how the conditions are enclosed by parentheses? They are currently all together - try bracketing the client ones together `WHERE container.phone_1 LIKE '264%' OR (client.phone_2 LIKE '264%' OR client_phone_3 LIKE '264%')`

Comment: I get the same result by trying to bracket client phones.
I also tried to perform two sepperate queries (first select from container and then from client) with only one field for phone returned (containers have only one and concat phones from client table) and join them using UNION, but that gives same rows 2 times having difference in phone field. So that is not working also!

Answer (score -1):

use and instead of where.

SELECT * FROM contract JOIN client ON contract.client_id = client.id 
JOIN container 
ON contract.contract_nr = container.contract_nr AND (container.phone_1 LIKE '264%'  client.phone_2 LIKE '264%' OR client_phone_3 LIKE '264%')

Comment: That's not valid SQL - you ***must*** have a WHERE clause to apply a condition, unless you are aggregating.